# Replacement for UPDATE statement with ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql-server

I am having a hard time trying to execute an update query that should contain ORDER BY clause, but I'm unable to find a proper solution yet.

```
UPDATE I
SET RefItemID = AQ.ID,
    I.MagParamNum = AQ.MagParamNum
FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._Items I
JOIN SRO_VT_SHARD.._Inventory INV ON INV.ItemID = I.ID64
JOIN SRO_VT_SHARD.._RefObjCommon ROC ON ROC.ID = I.RefItemID
JOIN _AEQItems AQ ON AQ.TypeID3 = ROC.TypeID3
                  AND AQ.TypeID4 = ROC.TypeID4
WHERE
    INV.Slot BETWEEN 0 AND 13 
    AND INV.Slot != 8 
    AND AQ.ReqLevel1 <= @Data2 
    AND INV.CharID = @CharID
ORDER BY AQ.ReqLevel1 DESC
```

Basically my query should work this way if `ORDER BY` clause is usable inside an update statement, but it doesn't. Is there something I can do which should solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: but what is the actual problem?, why do you want to use `ORDER BY` in that `UPDATE`?

Comment: Because in _AEQItems table, there are many rows that have the same TypeID3 and TypeID4 but different ReqLevel1, I want to update the column RefItemID in _Items table with the ID from _AEQItems which has the highest ReqLevel1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to determine the exact row to update for each `TypeID3` / `TypeID4` combination, and you can't do that in the outer query. You may need to add additional `ORDER BY` clauses here to break ties. You may also want to specify only a subset of columns if you have an index that covers the columns in `_AEQItems` used to search *and* the columns you're updating.

```
;WITH AQ AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY TypeID3, TypeID4 ORDER BY ReqLevel1 DESC)
  FROM _AEQItems
)
UPDATE I
SET RefItemID   = AQ.ID,
    MagParamNum = AQ.MagParamNum
FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._Items I
JOIN SRO_VT_SHARD.._Inventory INV ON INV.ItemID = I.ID64
JOIN SRO_VT_SHARD.._RefObjCommon ROC ON ROC.ID = I.RefItemID
JOIN AQ ON AQ.TypeID3 = ROC.TypeID3 AND AQ.TypeID4 = ROC.TypeID4
WHERE AQ.rn = 1 
  AND INV.Slot BETWEEN 0 AND 13 
  AND INV.Slot!=8 
  AND AQ.ReqLevel1 <= @Data2 
  AND INV.CharID = @CharID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery:

```
    UPDATE I
SET RefItemID=AQ.ID,I.MagParamNum=AQ.MagParamNum
FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._Items I
JOIN SRO_VT_SHARD.._Inventory INV ON INV.ItemID=I.ID64
JOIN SRO_VT_SHARD.._RefObjCommon ROC ON ROC.ID=I.RefItemID
JOIN (SELECT TypeID3, TypeID4, MAX(ReqLevel1) AS ReqLevel1 FROM _AEQItems GROUP BY TypeID3, TypeID4) AQ 
    ON AQ.TypeID3=ROC.TypeID3 
    AND AQ.TypeID4=ROC.TypeID4
WHERE INV.Slot BETWEEN 0 AND 13 AND INV.Slot!=8 AND AQ.ReqLevel1<=@Data2 AND INV.CharID=@CharID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate it.

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure _AutoEquipment, Line 26 [Batch Start Line 15]
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Try now. Since you want the higher ReqLevel1, use MAX

Comment: This will also need to account for ties. What if there are two rows with the same TypeID3/4 and the highest ReqLevel1 value? You'll update both rows. Accounting for ties is easier to do with windowing functions than with `MAX` (by adding a date column or identity to the order by, for example), but YMMV.